# How see console window of a service during your full execution lifetime?

Tags: c++, windows-services

Probably this already was answered here, but i not found.

Then i want know how execute a c++ **console application**/**service** (installs itself as service)  of way that i can see all output's (`printf()`) during your execution (similar to how happens in a normal console application when `system("pause");`is used in `main()`)? until now i'm able to see you console window only while Avast DeepScreen is executing he :-).

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDITION:**

I already insert `getchar();` in `ServiceMain()` and a `while (true) ... Sleep()` but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A service does not have a console window. And even if it did, a service does not run in an interactive desktop, so you couldn't see such a window anyway.

You need to rethink your logging approach. Either

- write your log messages to the Windows Event Log, and use the Windows Event Viewer to see the messages.
- create a separate visual app that runs in the user's interactive desktop and communicates with the service process to receive log messages. Then you can display the messages however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, take the execution of any program using a c++ program, you can simply do it using the command prompt.
Just type in :

```
    system(“path to the program”);
```

And, the program will be executed. If it’s a console window program, it will pop-up.
You can see the outputs, well, follow these :
    1   The System.Diagnostics.Trace class has a similar interface to the Console class so you could migrate your code quite easily to this.
    2   It can then be configured to output to a file. You can use the System.Diagnostics.EventLog class to write to the Event Log which you can then monitor using Event Viewer.
3   You can use the third-party open-source log4net library which is very flexible.